# read .html file from resources folder on server in spring boot

Tags: scala, spring-boot

I am trying to read demo.html file from resources in spring boot.
I have tried this codes but it is working in local-only not on server :

```
val demoFile = new File(this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("foo/demo.html").getFile)
val demoFile = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader.getResource("foo/demo.html").getFile)
val demoFile = new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader.getResource("foo/demo.html").getFile)
```

on server I am getting FileNotFoundException

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works locally because the file `demo.html` exists on your local machine. You can find it in a `build` folder or whatever your IDE uses to compile the code.

When you run your project on a server, you have only your project `jar` file, for example, `project.jar`. There is not `demo.html` file on a server.

`demo.html` is located inside `project.jar` file. `project.jar` is a simply ZIP archive. So you need a way to get a file from a ZIP archive (your `project.jar`).

The simplest way is to use streams. You can read a file, for example, in a string.

If you need to parse a file (it can be JSON, XML or HTML) you can pass a stream directly to the parsing library.

Also don't forget to close the stream (if it is not closed by the library, of course).

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access

Also you can copy a file from a jar to the `TEMP` folder and access it as an usual file.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I got the same solution from another source that we cannot get direct File from .jar so as you suggest I am using "getResourceAsStream" thank you